# Grails 3 : Passing an input stream in a service mthods

Tags: unit-testing, grails, service, mocking

I have a strange behavior with a service  unit test :

I have a service with a method  like this :

```
class FileVaultService {

    def grailsApplication

    FileEntry addFile(InputStream iStream) {

        log.debug("Ajout d'un fichier ${iStream} dans le vault.")

        // Do some stuff to copy the iStream in a file...
       Files.copy(iStream, targetFile.toPath())
     }
}
```

And my unit test :

```
@TestFor(FileVaultService)
@TestMixin(ServiceUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([Folder])
class FileVaultTests extends Specification {

    def log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass())


    void "test basic"() {
        when:
        File testFile = File.createTempFile("test", "test")
        testFile << "I am some content"

        InputStream inputStream = testFile.newInputStream()
        println "inputStream.available() = ${inputStream.available()}"

        FileEntry fileEntry = service.addFile(inputStream)
        println(fileEntry)


        then:
        "I am some content" == new File("${testFileVault}/${fileEntry.parentFolder.currentIndex}", fileEntry.realName).text
   }
}
```

But this test fails :

```
Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2908)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3027)
    at com.sayperhaps.services.FileVaultService.addFile(FileVaultService.groovy:50)
    at com.sayperhaps.service.FileVaultTests.test basic(FileVaultTests.groovy:78)
```

This is really strange, as the input stream is passed.
I can see it with some print statements, or by using a debugger.
But it is closed...

I've tried with and without @TestMixin(ServiceUnitTestMixin), but no difference.

Is there a mock mechanism doing some magic  I missed ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it...
The issue is in the log statement :

```
 FileEntry addFile(InputStream iStream) {

    log.debug("Ajout d'un fichier ${iStream} dans le vault.")
```

iStream.toString() closes the stream once its converted to a String.
Definitly not an issue with unit test framework